# Visual Studio Code - Removing Lines Containing criteria

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

This probably isn't a VS Code-specific question but it's my tool of choice.

I have a log file with a lot of lines containing the following:

`Company.Environment.Security.RightsBased.Policies.RightsUserAuthorizationPolicy`

Those are debug-level log records that clutter the file I'm trying to process.  I'm looking to remove the lines with that content.

I've looked into Regex but, unlike removing a blank line where you have the whole content in the search criteria (making find/replace easy), here I need to match from line break to line break on some criteria between the two, I think...

What are your thoughts on how criteria like that would work?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I think you should be able to just search for `^.*CONTENT.*$\n`, where the content is the text you showed us.  That is, search on the following pattern:

```
^.*Company\.Environment\.Security\.RightsBased\.Policies\.RightsUserAuthorizationPolicy.*$\n
```

And then just replace with empty string.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the periods in the middle `\.`

Comment: @aaldilai Thanks for the correction.  The pattern still would have worked, but for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: Maybe worth to note: In the Studio Code 'Regular expression' search mode should be enabled to be able to search with the RegExp.

Answer (score 176):

If the criteria is a particular string and you don't want to have to remember regexes, there is a few handy keyboard shortcuts that can help you out. I'm going to assume you're on a Mac.

1. Cmd-F to open find.
2. Paste your string.
3. Opt-Enter to select all of the instances of the string on the page.
4. Cmd-L to broaden the selection to the entire line of each instance on the page.
5. Delete/Backspace to remove those lines.

Comment: On Windows, replace "Cmd" with "Ctrl" and this works perfectly.

Comment: I also prefer this solution over the regex solution.  Matching text with special characters is easier/faster with this solution since you don't have to manually escape each special character.

Comment: Hi @James, can you please my this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64365300/how-can-i-remove-unused-imports-declarations-from-the-entire-project-of-react-ty

Comment: Another variant is to highlight one occurrence in the file, right-click, select Change All Occurances then do Ctrl+L and backspace.  I guess it's a combination of this answer and the one from Sanket Patel

Comment: this approach didn't screw up my yaml formatting unlike the regex approach

Comment: Thanks!! This worked great on a huge kafka dump file. I use Regex normally but using regex crashed VSCode.

btw 3 should be Opt-Enter instead of Alt-Enter

Answer (score 8):

I have already up-voted answer of @james. But.. still I found one more easy and many feature available extension in VS Code. [Here it is](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qcz.text-power-tools)

It have much easy options to apply filters.

To match specific case mentioned in question. I am attaching screenshot which display how to use for it. I am posting this for others who come here in search for same issue. (Like I came)
[image]

Comment: useless for larger files, keep showing error when use function "This function requires an active editor"