# How can I remove unused imports/declarations from the entire project of React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm trying to remove unused imports and declarations as answered in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57420207/7344164) for [Angular](https://angular.io/). I'm trying to achieve the goal using [eslint-plugin-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react), but not found any option to remove the unused imports and daclarations from the entire project, with a single command.

Here is my .eslintrc.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "unused-imports"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "warn",
            "tab"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "warn",
            "windows"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "warn",
            "double"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "warn",
            "always"
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "on",
        "unused-imports/no-unused-imports-ts": "on"
    }
}
```

Or is there a way to do the same using ESLint or Typescript Hero extensions in VS Code?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Using [`unused-imports`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-unused-imports) plugin and `unused-imports/no-unused-imports-ts` rule,  `eslint --fix` will remove the `import`s.

Here is an example repo which `--fix` removes the unused `import`s.

https://github.com/moshfeu/eslint-ts-unused-imports

### Old answer

*eslint* has a built-in [fix](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#fixing-problems) option.

```
eslint ... --fix
```

If `rules` contains `no-unused-vars`, eslint will "fix" the unused import by removing them (along with other [auto fixes](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/)).

Comment: Okay, can you please add a little about the right configuration of eslint?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear. I've updated my answer. Let me know if it's more clear now.

Comment: Glad to head :) If it answers your question, please accept it  so it will help to other people. Thanks.

Comment: The `no-unused-vars` rule actually does not have an auto fixer available. Imports will not be removed by default.

Comment: @MoshFeu - Your answer says `no-unused-vars` but your example repo uses `unused-imports/no-unused-imports-ts` (which works with --fix)

Comment: Just a heads-up in case if you're using eslint `--fix`, there is bug now which will remove the first comment after the unused import, which is a bit painful if you're trying to fix issues in a big project. See [issue](https://github.com/sweepline/eslint-plugin-unused-imports/issues/28)

Answer (score 48):

You can also use shortcuts in VSCode, if it needs to be done quickly and without extra effort:

- <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> for Mac
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> for Windows

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Any way to apply it to all files at once?

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou I couldn't find the way, but you can use npm packages that are offered for this case

Comment: Anyone else tried this with `0` instead of `o`? 

Comment: How do you apply this to the entire project? Which happens to be the question btw.

Answer (score 35):

Add this to your VS Code `settings.json`:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
   "source.fixAll": true,
   "source.organizeImports": true,
   "source.sortMembers": true
 }
```

Everytime you save a file it'll automatically remove the unused imports. It's a good method of house keeping for future edits but won't help existing unused imports, unless you go to those files directly.

Solution originally posted by **Damir Drempetić** here: https://dev.to/bornfightcompany/easily-sort-imports-and-remove-unused-declarations-on-each-save-in-vs-code-35k1

Comment: This is actually a lot better thanks @DanEngoMan

Comment: this does not fix the entire project, and that was the question

Comment: the correct format requires the value to be valid (but it works with a boolean), you should use something like this:     "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": "always",
        "source.organizeImports": "always",
        "source.sortMembers": "always"
    },

Answer (score 32):

##### TL;DR

Use `unused-imports/no-unused-imports` instead of `no-unused-vars`, as rule name.

---

If you're using the ESLint version, [eslint-plugin-unused-imports](https://github.com/sweepline/eslint-plugin-unused-imports), you may want to change the rule name to `unused-imports/no-unused-imports` instead of the blanket `no-unused-vars`.

```json
{
    "rules": {
        "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error"
    }
}
```

Refer to [the author's GitHub](https://github.com/sweepline/eslint-plugin-unused-imports#usage) for detailed usage.

For me, `no-unused-var` does not come with an auto fixer (it'll merely mentioned then number of errors/warnings but when I switch to `unused-imports/no-unused-imports`, all of the issues are *automagically* fixed.

Comment: does this work with typescript?

Comment: @ANimator120 yes, it works for me using Typescript.

Comment: Thank you! This works! I am also using `simple-import-sort`, so when I hit Save, not only does it order my imports, but this also removes any unused imports if I forget to remove them.

Answer (score -1):

`.eslintrc` file

```
"rules": {
 "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": 0
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.