# Why next lint not complaint of unused imports?

Tags: next.js

I have created Next.js project uinsg `npx create-next-app@latest`, and I have unused imports in the pages.

`npm run lint` does not complaint the unused imports until I added `eslint:recommended` in `.eslintrc.json`

```json
{
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "eslint:recommended"]
}
```

Is this the recommended way?

Comment: You can add you own rule below.  

I think you need `unused-imports` plugin.  

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68338238/2018591

Comment: I guess `next/core-web-vitals` simply not include the rules to check unused imports. That is why we need `eslint:recommended` to detect the unused imports.
It looks like `eslint-plugin-unused-imports` is needed only if we want ESLint to remove the unused imports automatically.

Comment: "is needed only if we want ESLint to remove the unused imports automatically"

It should also highlight unused imports in your IDE and error if you run eslint

Comment: "is needed only if we want ESLint to remove the unused imports automatically"

It should also highlight unused imports in your IDE and error if you run eslint